# selecting results with range + Pythagoras theorem

Tags: php, mysql, math

i have a mysql table for uk people that includes:

- postcode beginning (i.e. BB2)
- latitude (int)
- longitude (int)
- range (int, in miles, 1-20)

http://www.easypeasy.com/guides/article.php?article=64 - theres the article for the sql file i based my table on

now it says i can use Pythagoras theorem to calculate distances based on longitude and latitude.

so lets say i wanted to select all the people who are in range (based on the 1-20 they enter in the range field) of a postcode beginning i search for

for example, lets say i search for "BB2", i want a query that will select all of the people whose postcode beginning is "BB2", AND all the people within range of BB2 (going by the 1-20 mile range in their database field).

can some math whiz help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Google revealed [this](http://jan.ucc.nau.edu/~cvm/latlon_formula.html) - the code's in PERL but you can figure out the logic.

> **Formula and code for calculating distance based on two lat/lon locations**
>
> The following is the formula I use in
>   perl to do the calculations.  Perl
>   expects all of the angles to be in
>   radians.
>
> ```
> return &acos(cos($a1)*cos($b1)*cos($a2)*cos($b2) + cos($a1)*sin($b1)*cos($a2)*sin($b2) + sin($a1)*sin($a2)) * $r;
>
>
> Where:
>
> $a1 = lat1 in radians
> $b1 = lon1 in radians
> $a2 = lat2 in radians
> $b2 = lon2 in radians
> $r = radius of the earth in whatever units you want
> ```
>
> The values I use for radius of the
>   earth are:
>
> 3963.1 statute miles
>   3443.9 nautical miles 6378 km
>
> To convert the decimal degrees to
>   radians use the following perl.
>
> ```
> # define an accurate value for PI
>
> $pi = atan2(1,1) * 4;
>
> #
> # make sure the sign of the angle is correct for the direction
> # West an South are negative angles
> #
>
> $degrees = $degrees * -1 if $direction =~ /[WwSs]/;
> $radians = $degrees*($pi/180);
> ```
>
> To convert degree minutes and seconds
>   to decimal degrees use the following
>   perl formula.
>
> ```
> $dec_deg = $deg + ($min + $sec/60)/60;
> ```
>
> Finally, there is no acos function in
>   perl so here is the function I use.  I
>   don't remember where I got the math
>   for this.
>
> ```
> # subroutine acos
> #
> # input: an angle in radians
> #
> # output: returns the arc cosine of the angle
> #
> # description: this is needed because perl does not provide an arc cosine function
> sub acos {
>     my($x) = @_;
>     my $ret = atan2(sqrt(1 - $x**2), $x);        return $ret;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

no it says you can calculate distances base on x,y coordinates not longitude-latitude (using Pythagoras theorem).

to calculate distance between 2 points (x1,y1) & (x2,y2):

```
d = SquareRoot((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
```

using longitude-latitude, you can see here: [Calculate distance, bearing and more between two Latitude/Longitude points](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)